# How can I call a Parent with at least one Child of a Child relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, relational-database, pg

I have a Parent object that has a child object, that *can* have many grandchild objects.

I am looking for an elegant **scope** for that works with PG to derive a Parent who has at least one grandchild object.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :childs
   # scope :has_grandchildren ...
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many   :grandchilds
   belongs_to :parent
end

class Grandchild < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :child
end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs
  has_many :grandchilds, :through => :childs
  scope    :has_grandchildren, childs.includes(:grandchilds).group("childs.id").having("count(grandchilds.id) < 0")
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :grandchilds
  belongs_to :parent
end

class Grandchild < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child
end
```

I added the `has_many through` relationship in case you needed it later, although it is optional.

Comment: This causes  `syntax error, unexpected tLAMBDA, expecting keyword_end`. I'm using ruby 1.9.3 @Niali

Comment: Typo ha sorry put the quote the wrong side of the bracket.

Comment: Strange, same error. I'm pretty sure lambdas work in 1.9.3 with that syntax.

Comment: Try that now @Trip, had assumed you were on ruby 2/Rails 4, didn't see your comment.

Comment: It appears that one can't use the syntax `childs` as the initial call in the scope. I think in Rails 4 you can do that. I get `undefined local variable or method `childs' for #<Class`

Comment: No it's complaining now that the scope is being called on the class, not the instance. Like the Parent Class doesn't have grandchildren, but a instance of the parent class might have grandchildren. I gotta run, but let me think about this, one thing you could do is turn it into a method

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to do this.  `includes` is an outer join.  `joins` is an inner join which will exclude results that have 0 childs or 0 grandchilds.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs

  scope    :has_grandchildren, joins(:childs => :grandchilds).uniq
end
```